# A strange disconnect with Rails and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, disconnect

The Rails 4 app had been working for 5 months flawlessly, but some minutes ago it started to encounter an error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds))
```

The DBMS is a locally installed MySQL.

It did not matter how many times I tried to reload pages or refer to different URLs of an application.

The problem was gone only after I restarted the Rails app.

What was it and how to make the app to solve this issue automatically without admin's intervention?

Comment: Can you connect to the database directly from the command line on the server using the same credentials as you have set up for your rails application?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you have in your database.yml

```
{environment_name}:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: {product_name}_environment_name
  username: username
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Add correct values for 'reaping_frequency' and 'pool' in connection parameter and it might look like

```
{environment_name}:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
 database: {product_name}_environment_name
 pool: 15
 reaping_frequency: 3
 username: username
 password: password
 socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Options descriptions

```
pool: number indicating size of connection pool (default 5)

checkout_timeout: number of seconds to block and wait for a connection before giving up and raising a timeout error (default 5 seconds).

reaping_frequency: frequency in seconds to periodically run the Reaper, which attempts to find and close dead connections, which can occur if a programmer forgets to close a connection at the end of a thread or a thread dies unexpectedly. (Default nil, which means don't run the Reaper).

dead_connection_timeout: number of seconds from last checkout after which the Reaper will consider a connection reapable. (default 5 seconds).
```

Comment: with `reaping_frequency: 3` things went even worse.